# TransferFrom function does not work even with approve

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, erc-20

I'm trying to create a market contract using the token I created as the currency. The market works by placing asks and bids and then using `transferFrom` function to hold onto the tokens. However the function fails even though I have approved the contract address.
Here is my "Ask" method.

```
function addAsk (uint _amount, uint _price) public {
    string memory _timestamp = uint2str(block.timestamp);
    Ask storage ask = asks[msg.sender];
    ask.asker = msg.sender;
    ask.amount = _amount;
    ask.price = _price;
    ask.timestamp = _timestamp;
    ask_ids.push(msg.sender);
    //Works until here
    credits.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    emit AskPlaced(msg.sender, _amount, _price, _timestamp, tick);
  }
```

Here is how I implemented my ERC20 token in the contract:

```
IERC20 public credits;


constructor() {
credits = new EnergyCredits();
    
}
```

I am getting this error every single time.
[image]

I have pinpointed the problem to the following location:
[image]

It seems the transferFrom function is having trouble when doing math operations to the "balances" mapping. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Take a look at your EnergyCredits code，Have your tokens been allocated?
Take a look at your front-end code, there may be a problem.

Comment: How are you approving the tokens?

Comment: `
function approve(address spender, uint256 tokens)
        public
        override
        returns (bool success)
    {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    } 
`
This is the method I use to approve the spender. I use Remix IDE with solidity 0.8.6 to approve the contract address as a spender.

Comment: @BatuBüktel Please indicate where do you call approve, and how are you calling it (parameters used). In solc v0.8 airthmetic operations are checked for overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this problem by using Open Zeppelin library to create my token. For some reason, I couldn't get my contract to work with my token contract.